# Який варіант слова є правильнішим: "напис" чи "надпис"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

У тлумачному словнику (http://sum.in.ua/s/nadpys) дізнаємось, що "*на**д**пи*с" це те саме що, '*напис*'. 
Чи дійсно значення слів не відрізняються і яке з них природніше для вживання у мовленні?

Comment: Це те саме. Проте «надпис» у мовленні зустрічається набагато рідше, якщо, звісно, не в жіночому роді :-) Можна пофантазувати, що префікс «над-» несе якийсь особливий зміст, але я не знайшов підтверджень цьому. Хоча результатом «надписування» буде саме «надпис», та це штучна побудова.

Comment: @Ukurainajin там дійсно є підтвердження, в етимології цих слів, що префікси в них відповідно означають «над» – це над чимось  і «на» – на чомусь, але не знайшов жодних результатів, що ці слова мають означати щось дійсно різне. В тих слов'янських мовах, для яких я знайшов означення для цих слів, здається, що «надпис» є таким собі або неповним або застарілим синонімом до слова «напис» (крім хорватської).

Comment: Суб'єктивно для мене «надпис над заголовком» і «напис над заголовком», «надпис на монеті» і «напис на монеті» — одне й те саме, хоча я віддав би перевагу слову «напис». Але «надпис назви міста» спершу виглядає  кострубато у порівнянні з «напис назви міста». Хоча це можна пояснити незвичкою: після тривалого пошуку на цю тему, де постійно доводилося стикатися із словом «надпис», я настільки звик до нього, що вже не бачу різниці між ним і словом «напис» в останньому прикладі.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Напис" є найбільш вживаним та природнішим.

Як слушно зауважив @Sasha, "Щодо «найбільш вживаним» можна підтвердити, наприклад, кількістю вжитків у гугл-книжках українською ([430](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81&num=100&lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&start=400) vs. [175](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81&num=100&lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&start=100)), або у [частотному словнику художньої прози MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/cfq.aspx?fdid=hproz) (238 vs. 8), або лейпцизькому корпусі 2014 ([18 875](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) vs. [1 670](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81))."

Щодо ж природнішого, то відносна вживаність також є й непрямим свідоцтвом того, як слово сприймають більшість мовців. (@Sasha, дякую ще раз за це спостереження.)

Додам, що мені особисто (суб'єктивно, звісно) варіант "надпис" відчувається або як суржик (свідоме чи несвідоме уподібнення до російського "надпись"), або як архаїзм (у прикладах з класиків у словниках чи деінде можна зустріти, але то тексти сторічної чи більше давності).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, завжди обґрунтовуйте ваші відповіді. [Ось корисний допис](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/), який розповідає, які запитання і відповіді ми вважаємо якісними, а які — ні.

Comment: @Sasha, признаюсь, мені й на думку не спало шукати статистично-цифрове підтвердження в цьому випадку, настільки "надпис" мені "не звучить" українським словом. Втім, Ваше люб'язне доповнення підтверджує невелику вживаність, хоча результат у гугл-книжках мене трохи дивує, mova.info (~3%) найближче до очікуваного, цікаво було б порівняти субстрати, але я за це не візьмусь, даруйте.

Comment: @Sasha, так, сприйняття природне-неприродне - суб'єктивне, хоч я б чекав, що переважна більшість мовців матимуть таке ж саме відчуття...Так чи інакше, відносно мала вживаність опосередковано свідчить на користь меншої природності для більшості мовців, ні? ;) 
На мою думку сучасний мовець в теперішній, доволі русифікованій, Україні вживатиме "наДпис" тільки помилково, через вплив відповідного російського слова "надпись" яке може бути більше "на слуху".

Answer (score 2):

Загляньмо в СУМ.

> [НА́ДПИС](http://sum.in.ua/s/nadpys), у, чол. Те саме, що напис. Мармурові скрині над значними покійниками, з пишними арабськими надписами.. пообсипались та завалились від часу (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 121); На стіні естради і ще в двох-трьох місцях розліплені свіжі афіші з надписом великими червоними літерами: «Підеш — не вернешся» (Іван Кочерга, II, 1956, 65).

> [НА́ПИС](http://sum.in.ua/s/napys), у, чол. Короткий текст, уміщений на чому-небудь. На полуденній стіні церкви була залізна дошка з написом над могилою гетьмана (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 338); Юрко запримітив умить якісь написи, видряпані, мабуть, нігтем на сірих стінах (Петро Козланюк, Ю. Крук, 1957, 406);
> //  Стародавній текст, вирізьблений, висічений і т. ін. на твердому матеріалі. Часом з'являвся несподівано у фрамузі стіни фонтан, весь покарбований написами з корану (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 123); Розпечене азербайджанське сонце сліпучо виграє на сірих надгробках з тюркськими написами, зазирає у темні западини печер (Олесь Донченко, II, 1956, 80).

Як на мене, "афіша з надписом" чується природніше, ніж "афіша з написом". Назагал, надпис: (1) конкретний текст, а не просто "якийсь" напис; (2) надпис може бути друкований, напис радше писаний рукошма; (3) резолюція директора над текстом заяви є, безперечно, і напис, і надпис.

Comment: Не розумію як із тлумачень СУМу випливають Ваші висновки. Чи це не висновки, а просто дві різні позиції (мовляв, по-СУМівськи і на Ваш погляд)?